# How to prevent rsync users from using -t?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sftp

I run a server on which we provide sftp credentials to clients for delivery of files of various size.  It's important to me to retain the time uploaded, and I honestly couldn't give a crap about the time it was created or modified on the original system.  Unfortunately, many of our clients *insist* on using `rsync -av` to upload their files.

I've already done a lot - used chroot to sandbox users, prevented ssh access, etc, but this continues to be a pain in our ass.  Is there a way to prevent rsync or sftp from changing creation/modification times server side?

I've tried googling, but I can't seem to provide the right constellation of terms to weed out all the articles/questions by people trying to *use* rsync from the client side.

Comment: Is this rsync over ssh over using an rsync daemon?

Comment: Do the accounts have shell access or just sftp/rsync access? (More specifically... it sounds like people are using the rsync client to talk to an sftp server... which I didn't know was possible. Is that what's happening or am I mis-reading the question?)

Comment: @TomOnTime There's no shell access - the ssh config is used to prevent login and allow SFTP.  @Mark-Wagner I wasn't aware that rsync had its own daemon - `sudo ps aux | grep [r]sync` returns nothing.

Comment: Probably OP's clients are using `rsync` over `sshfs`. Contrary to the name `sshfs` runs on bare `sftp` and doesn't require enabled `ssh` access.

Answer (score 3):

I would script my way around `inotifywait -r -m --csv -e ATTRIB /my/dir` . This prints any file as soon as someone modifies either mtime,  ctime, permissions (and other minor stufF) so you can just `touch` that file per your requirements. It's a cumbersome and ugly workaround, but can't think of anything simpler for the general case.

Your requirement to update `mtime` is non-standard; it's ok with `ctime`. Normally you let people go backwards with `mtime` freely, so that it can store the date when the contents of the file were *meaningfully* updated. The time when something about the file changed (for example mtime changed, permissions changed, file was created, etc.) is checked with `ctime`; see `stat /my/file` or `ls -lc` or locate the latest with `find . -cmin -60`

Answer (score 0):

The server-side authorized_keys file can supply a "COMMAND=" argument which means "If someone used this key, ignore the command that would have executed on the server and run this command instead."  This command is given all the flags and options that the default command would have received.  You can supply a command that removes flags that you don't want and then runs the expected command.  An article about something similar is here: https://cybermashup.com/2013/05/14/restrict-ssh-logins-to-a-single-command/

The problem with this answer is that I'm not sure if the "-t" flag is communicated this way, or is it in the RSYNC protocol.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, (a) clients are not using keys to connect, no matter how many times I try to convince them, and (b), ssh is already denied - none of these users can get a shell.